# Using Kentico 7 API via Console App

Tags: c#, kentico

I have the following, using Kentico API 7 via a console application:

```
String connectionString = CMS.DataEngine.ConnectionHelper.GetConnectionString("MyConnString");
Console.WriteLine("connectionString ? " + connectionString);
//CMS.DataEngine.GeneralConnection
CMS.DataEngine.GeneralConnection conn = CMS.DataEngine.ConnectionHelper.GetConnection(connectionString);
conn.Open();
Console.WriteLine("connection is open? " + conn.IsOpen());

CMS.CMSHelper.CMSContext.Init();
Console.WriteLine("CurrentSiteID " + CMS.CMSHelper.CMSContext.CurrentSiteID);
```

The connection is open. I get error 
 `Console.WriteLine("CurrentSiteID " + CMS.CMSHelper.CMSContext.CurrentSiteID);`

that says connection is not initialized. Got help?

Comment: You can't do that! CMSContext is not initialized in console app and I'm not sure if you even can initialize it correctly in console all.   
What is the reason of doing that?

Comment: The kentico 7 document says that line of code has to be in an external application. If that's not right, then what do I use for kentico API 7?

Comment: "The kentico 7 document says that line of code has to be in an external application" - this phrase out of context means nothing. I used Kentico 7 earlier. What is that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I would like to make a connection to database to be able to delete some data from some tables, all done through a console app calling the  kentico 7 api. The error I get says my connection is not initialized. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It certainly is possible to use Kentico API outside of Kentico itself. Recently, I published an [article](http://devnet.kentico.com/articles/take-advantage-of-kentico%E2%80%99s-nuget-feed-and-build-your-own-apps) on this topic. However, the article demonstrates the possibility on a newer version of Kentico. But back to your problem...

The `CMS.CMSHelper.CMSContext.Init();` method expects a connection string named "CMSConnectionString" to exist in your app.config or web.config.

The [documentation](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/7_0/devguide/index.html?using_api_and_cms_controls_outside_cms_project.htm) also says

> You can call this method at any point in your application's life cycle, but it must occur before you use any other Kentico CMS API.

so you should not be touching `CMS.DataEngine` or any other `CMS.*` namespace before you call `CMSContext.Init()`. 
Once you call that method you can start using the parameter-less overload `ConnectionHelper.GetConnection()` but I would advise you to take advantage of the [Info-Provider pattern](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/7_0/devguide/database_table_api.htm) that Kentico offers instead of using the direct DB access through `CMS.DataEngine`.

For instance, this is how you [delete users](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/7_0/devguide/membership_api_examples_managing_users.htm?zoom_highlightsub=userinfoprovider):

```
// Get the user
UserInfo deleteUser = UserInfoProvider.GetUserInfo("MyNewUser");

// Delete the user
UserInfoProvider.DeleteUser(deleteUser);
```

Comment: Exactly what was needed. A big help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's a specific need to create a console application to perform your task, then I would recommend avoiding a console app and instead creating a custom [scheduled task](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Scheduling+custom+tasks).

You can write the code that your task needs to perform within the App_Code folder of your project - or within the CMSAppCode project if you're using a web application project type.  This way you don't have to worry about having access to the database or referencing all the DLLs you'll need to utilize the Kentico API.

Comment: What version of kentico api is this that you mention scheduled task? I'm using api 7

Comment: It's been around since at least version 4.  Here's the documentation for v7: http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/7_0/devguide/index.html  .  Let me know if you're not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to do this in a console application. I am not sure how to proceed here

Comment: Well if you think you absolutely have to, there's a lot that goes into that.  Here's a guide that should get you started : http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/7_0/devguide/index.html?using_api_and_cms_controls_outside_cms_project.htm

Comment: Yes. Thank you, but I did read this before. That's why I am on this post. It seems this information toggles back and forth between a web and console application. The directions aren't the best to follow. Nevertheless I don't know if the context call in the console app is working as its a statement with no return value. As you can see, I used it in my question entry.

Comment: I would like to thank you for taking the time to answer this post !!!!!  Any help is appreciated 