# Kentico 7 console App

Tags: c#, kentico

A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in CMS.GlobalHelper.dll  error when it gets to this line in the code

```
// Save to database
node.Update();
```

All other lines in the code contain values. The code needs to update a `NodeAliasPath` on one of the pages.

```
// Create an instance of the Tree provider first
TreeProvider tree = new TreeProvider(CMSContext.CurrentUser);

//Gets all the nodes that have the node alias path of Dinning-Commons
var nodes = tree.SelectNodes("SietName", "%contains part of nodealispath%", "en-us", false);        

if (nodes != null)
{
    // Loop through all documents
    foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("NodeAliasPath before change  " + node.NodeAliasPath);
        file.WriteLine("              ");
        file.WriteLine("NodeAliasPath before change  " + node.NodeAliasPath);
        Console.WriteLine("              ");
        file.WriteLine("              ");        

        String newNodeAliasPath = node.NodeAliasPath.Replace("old node alias path", "new node alias path);    

        //Set the value this way
        bool returnNodeValue = node.SetValue("NodeAliasPath", newNodeAliasPath);
Console.WriteLine(" returnNodeValue " + returnNodeValue);        

        //Or set value thos way
        Console.WriteLine(" return value from  Set Value -- NodeAlias Path  " + node.SetValue("NodeAliasPath", newNodeAliasPath));
        Console.WriteLine("    __________________________      ");
        file.WriteLine(" return value from  Set Value -- NodeAlias Path  " + node.SetValue("NodeAliasPath", newNodeAliasPath));
        file.WriteLine(" __________________________ ");        

        // Save to database----NULL REFERNCE IN CMSHELPER.DLL Here. Code hangs
        node.Update();
```

Comment: Have you initialized the API before you started using any of the Kentico classes? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34955846/using-kentico-7-api-via-console-app

Comment: YES>//Initialize console application  to use Kentico API
            CMS.CMSHelper.CMSContext.Init();

Comment: Initialization happens before anything else.The entire program works up until the node.update point

Comment: What is that you're trying to accomplish? Why don't you want to use Scheduled task for this, or even user control?

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what the problem is - the `CMSContext.CurrentUser` is null within context of a console app... Initialize the `TreeProvider` with a specific user like this:

```
UserInfo user = UserInfoProvider.GetUserInfo("administrator");
TreeProvider tree = new TreeProvider(user);
```

Another reason could be that you're trying to change `NodeAliasPath`. Moving a document is not a trivial operation. I'd recommend using `TreeProvider.MoveNode()` or `DocumentHelper.MoveDocument()` to be sure the DB will remain consistent.

Comment: Well, actually there is not an issue with TreeProvider tree = new TreeProvider(CMSContext.CurrentUser); (Thanks)

Comment: It doesn't have to throw at that specific line ;) it'll throw an exception later when the user object is actually accessed...